# Mongo query find where last character doesn't need to match

Tags: mongodb, scala

say I have a 6 character field in a Mongo collection, I want to match all entries on the first 5 characters, ignoring the 6th no matter what it is. The entries will always be 6 characters long so no need to accommodate for longer entries.

I am using Scala with MongoDB with the find query.

My regex is `val regex = "^([A-Za-z0-9]{5}).*$"`

My query is `find("id" → JsString(id))`

I realise I need to actually use my regex somewhere in the find query but I'm not sure how. Please help. Many thanks, Jackie

Comment: If you want to find a six-character String that starts with "ABCDE", I'm guessing your id regex will need to be something like `^ABCDE.$`.

Comment: Maybe something like `find(regex("id", "^ABCDE.$"))` will work (using http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.3/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/Filters$.html#regex(fieldName:String,pattern:String):org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson)

Comment: Thank you @JamesWhiteley but how do I search using a given id and the regex?

Comment: I don't understand how to put both the id that I'm looking for and the regex into the find query, Many thanks